# Convert Keras model to quantized Tensorflow Lite model that can be used on Edge TPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite, tpu

I have a Keras model that I want to run on the Coral Edge TPU device. To do this, it needs to be a Tensorflow Lite model with full integer quantization. I was able to convert the model to a TFLite model:

```py
model.save('keras_model.h5')

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file("keras_model.h5")
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

But when I run `edgetpu_compiler converted_model.tflite`, I get this error:

```
Edge TPU Compiler version 2.0.267685300
Invalid model: converted_model.tflite
Model not quantized
```

This is because I need to quantize the model, but I'm not sure how to do that. I found [this page](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization#full_integer_quantization_of_weights_and_activations) which tells me how to do this, but it wants me to make an input data generator. This is the example it provides:

```py
def representative_dataset_gen():
  for _ in range(num_calibration_steps):
    # Get sample input data as a numpy array in a method of your choosing.
    yield [input]
```

How can I adapt this code to work with my input data? Where does `num_calibration_steps` come from? Is there a better way to do this? (I saw references to `tf.contrib.tpu.keras_to_tpu_model` but it has been deprecated)

Answer (score 3):

I believe `num_calibration_steps` is just the number of times the converter uses your rep set to determine the quantization levels. Just a guess, but maybe it subsamples from your rep set multiple times (bootstrapping or jackknifing). I'm still investigating the whole process myself, but it seems to work for me if I just pass it a single image for each yield, and use `num_calibration_steps` at about 100 (e.g., 100 representative images). You can see my demo script [on github](https://github.com/mattroos/EdgeTpuTesting/blob/master/test_edgetpu.ipynb).

The key part is:

```
image_shape = (56, 56, 32)

def representative_dataset_gen():
    num_calibration_images = 10
    for i in range(num_calibration_images):
        image = tf.random.normal([1] + list(image_shape))
        yield [image]
```

Also see my similar response to this question:
[Post-training full integer quantization of Keras model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58623192/post-training-full-integer-quantization-of-keras-model/58666509#58666509)

Comment: I did a little more testing. It seems that representative_dataset_gen() must yield one and only one image, in the format I described. So no bootstrapping or jackknifing. The num_calibration_steps variable might be more aptly named num_calibration_images. Though there is nothing to prevent someone for using the same image more than once, so I guess num_calibration_steps still works and is a more general description.

Comment: Thanks. Your simple example helped me solve my bug. I initially yielded a single image either as 3D array (HxWxC) in a list (i.e. `[3d_image_array]`) or as a 4D array (NxHxWxC). But seemingly TfLite wants the generator to yield a 4D array in a list (i.e. `[4d_image_array]`) Brrr, nasty bug